# How to fix Zathura showing blank pages in compiled two page LaTeX document?

Tags: viewers

Here is the minimal LaTeX file that can be used to produce the problem (on my computer):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{fullpage,url,amssymb,epsfig,color,xspace,tikz,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Title}
hi
\pagebreak

stack overflow..
\end{document}
```

I'm using Emacs and AucTex, and this seems to be the beginning of the compile output:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error  --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

I have Zathura as my viewer. Usually Zathura works fine, but this time I am getting this weird preview, and I have no idea why:
[image]

Is there any reason for this? I am using WSL2, Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, zathura version as follows apparently:

```
zathura 0.3.8
(plugin) pdf-poppler (0.2.8) (/usr/lib/zathura/pdf.so)
```

Edit: I don't really know what's going on here. What I did to produce my minimal example was eventually reduce the content in the subsections, and keep recompiling and calling the viewer again (with Emacs command `C-c C-a`), and I saw that this kept happening. However, when I just paste my minimal example into an empty buffer and call `C-c C-a`, it works fine. So I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Do the packages have any influence on this behavior, i.e., does it also occur without packages? If there are irrelevant packages then you can minimize your example further, this may help with pinpointing the issue - it might be caused by a package, but if it also occurs without packages then it is more likely to be caused by some setting in your viewer instead.

Comment: that looks to be a setting in your pdf reader showing two page spreads as in a book with odd pages on the right and even pages on the left.

Comment: unrelated but don't load `epsfig` unless you need to emulate latex 2.09 documents from the 1980s. I wrote that in 1994 as a legacy wrapper for documents that were old then...

Comment: @Marijn The problem is, it only seems to happen with this particular viewer, zathura. Every other viewer works fine. Also, equally relevant is that, every other time it works. That is, with the same header packages, zathura displays things fine usually. For some reason only sometimes this weird thing happens, not always... I'll try removing some packages though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you know such a setting for zathura, or the more general term to be able to find it in a search engine? I can't find any such setting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle made some edits, so I don't think the problem is with the editor settting to be honest

Comment: Looks like it's just viewing side by side. In this case odd pages are always on the right hand side. It just looks like there are blank pages, but there aren't really. Make a longer document (e.g., 5 pages) and you'll see what is going on. You can toggle this view this option with the `d` key. It's always happening for this document because `zathura` remembers it's settings on a per file case.

Comment: Thank you very much, @DavidPurton. That solves it. I didn't know this was an option, must have pressed `d` by accident.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was caused by an undesired PDF viewer configuration setting.

Comment: clearly @DavidPurton described it better as that's what I was trying to say:-)